# When an option selected I wanna change the other select tags options

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, html-select

In my Django template I have two select tag. I want to change the second tag to be linked to the first. For example when in first tag animals option select I want to show the animals on the second select tag. When plants select in first tag I want to show plants in the second select tag. How can I do this?

```
       (animals or plants)
      <select id="creatures">
        {% for x in list %}

          <option value="{{x.creature}}">{{x.creature}}</option>

        {% endfor %}
      </select>



          <select id="instances">

            {% for y in instances %}

              <option value="{{y.instance}}">{{x.instance}}</option>

            {% endfor %}
          </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways.

Here is one approach you can take:

[Try it in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/st-taussig-6ti10u-6ti10u?file=/index.js)

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const selectedOption = e.target.value;

  // update second select based on what is selected
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = getSecondSelectOptions(
    selectedOption
  );
});

function getSecondSelectOptions(category) {
  const animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird"];
  const plants = ["lily", "lotus"];
  if (category === "animals")
    return animals
      .map((value) => `<option value="${value}">${value}</option>`)
      .join("");
  else if (category === "plants")
    return plants
      .map((value) => `<option value="${value}">${value}</option>`)
      .join("");
  else return ""; // clear second select
}
```

We're updating the contents of the second select using `innerHTML`.

Another approach would be to have different select elements written statically but **hidden** by default. Then you can unhide the select element you want based on the option selected in the first select.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I should write datas from database. Because of that I should use djangos template tagging {{}}. @code